# Querying conversations from messages table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the messages table formatted as follows:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id|sender_id| recipient_id | message_text |created_at            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | 2       |  10          | "test1"      |"2017-04-10 09:05:45" |
| 2 | 10      |  2           | "test2"      |"2017-04-10 09:05:47" |
| 3 | 2       |  4           | "test3"      |"2017-04-10 09:05:49" |
| 4 | 10      |  4           | "test4"      |"2017-04-10 09:05:51" |
| 5 | 4       |  2           | "test5"      |"2017-04-10 09:05:53" |
| 6 | 2       |  10          | "test6"      |"2017-04-10 09:05:58" |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is get all the "conversations" of a logged in user (say user with id 2), along with the last messages for that conversation.
I managed to pull out the id's of users user2 has messages with using this query:

```
select distinct users.id 
from messages, users where 
(recipient_id = 2 and users.id = sender_id) 
or 
(sender_id = 2 and users.id = recipient_id);
```

What this yields is

```
4
10
```

as user2 has either sent and/or received messages from these two people (`test1, test2, test6` for `10`, and `test3, test5` for `4`).

What I can't do is modify this query so it also yields the last message sent to or received by the yielded id - for example

```
4  | test5
10 | test6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to obtain the most recent message date for every conversation involving a certain user.  In this case, we can aggregate over conversations for a given user and retain the most recent message date.

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id)    AS first,
           GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id) AS second,
           MAX(created_at) AS recent_date
    FROM messages
    WHERE sender_id = 2 OR recipient_id = 2
    GROUP BY LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id),
             GREATEST(sender_id, recipient_id)
) m2
    ON LEAST(m1.sender_id, m1.recipient_id)    = m2.first AND
       GREATEST(m1.sender_id, m1.recipient_id) = m2.second AND
       m1.created_at = m2.recent_date
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

The challenge in this query is to find a way to group conversations between two users together.  I used the `LEAST/GREATEST` trick, which is a way that we can treat a `2 -> 4` and `4 -> 2` conversation as being logically the same thing.  Then, using `GROUP BY`, we can identify the most recent conversation date for that pair of conversing users.  So the subquery in my answer above finds, for each pair of users, without regard of any order, that pair along with its most recent conversation date.  We then join this result back to the `messages` table to bring in the actual latest message text.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: This indeed gives me almost the result that I need, but i need the messages most recent messages instead of their dates. If i just add message text to select, the part you did with dates are still correct, but messages I get don't match the dates. I like the approach, could you also explain a bit how you got to this solution?

Comment: the modified query works like a charm! I'd really love to hear a bit about what you did there, I don't want to just copy/paste it haha :)

Comment: @hpdobrica I gave you a deeper explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

Use an `order_by created_at desc` statement at the end of your query to get the most recent messages.

Comment: This won't give the desired result, since your approach would leave us with just one record.

Comment: `select distinct users.id, messages.message_text
from messages, users 
where
(recipient_id = 2 and users.id = sender_id)
or
(sender_id = 2 and users.id = recipient_id) order by messages.created_at desc;`
this gives me all the messages to/from user 2 ordered from newest to oldest. Also when i add message_text to select, i no longer get only 2 records but all the messages, that's also the part of the problem.